# C++ Timer Problem

Tags: c++, winapi

I've written a timer class. After starting the timer, I would like to know if 20 seconds has been passed or not, if it is, I would like to call a function or perform a block of code. That class doesn't work but I Don't know why .

EDIT:  By it doesn't work I mean that isTimeTout(seconds) always return true; I would like just to see if few seconds has been passed, and based on that do an action. 
    class timer {
        private:
            unsigned long begTime;
        public:
            void start() {
                begTime = clock();
            }

```
        unsigned long elapsedTime() {
            return ((unsigned long) clock() - begTime) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        }

        bool isTimeout(unsigned long seconds) {
            return seconds >= elapsedTime();
        }
};
```

Comment: This class should work to check if the specified time has passed using the `isTimeout` function, obviously it won't give you an automatic notification, for that you have to use some OS facilities...

Comment: How exactly does it not work? What's going wrong with it?

Comment: You need to provide more information.  What does "doesn't work" mean?  Show how you're using your class.

Comment: I mean it doesn't inform me if 20 seconds has been passed for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're on Windows, you can stick with using `clock()`.

The error is here:

```
return seconds >= elapsedTime();
```

it should be:

```
return seconds <= elapsedTime();
```

What you have right now will return `true` when ***less than*** 20 seconds has elapsed. Flipping the comparison should fix it.

Answer (score 3):

`clock()` measures CPU time not wall time. Try using `time()` along with `difftime()` instead.

Comment: `clock()` measures wall-time in Windows. The question is tagged winapi.

Comment: Does time() and difftime() should be Polled to work ???? that doesn't satisfy my needs ..

Answer (score 0):

Try using time() and difftime() like stated above. I've had this problem before too :)

Comment: If your answer is already here, just up vote it. Don't provide duplicate answers.